# &lt; that is not in HTML source code appears when loading page on the web

Tags: html, google-chrome, debugging, web, firefox

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how this `&lt;` (which is the code for the bracket <) appears on my pure HTML page when loading it on the web. It appears both in Firefox and Chrome:

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr5gA.jpg)

The `&lt;` code is NOT there when I upload the page or check the source code directly on the server with my FTP client:

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riAkm.jpg)

I cannot see the `&lt;` when displaying the source code of the entire page on the web either. I can only see it when selecting the text in the area and then"showing selection source":

[screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qniMX.jpg)

Is this some sort of browser bug that affects both Firefox and Chrome? I cannot think of any other explanation.

The page: http://www.weltsprachen.net/ukrainisch-lernprogramme.html (in German). Other pages on the same website with almost exactly the same code do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged your source code. You have an extra < in your table.

```
<<td><center>PC, Mac, Android, iOS</center></td>
```

It's under Duolingo. Get rid of the extra < and it should disappear.

Also check out your `<p>` tags some of them are opened but not closed with a `</p>`.

The only other thing I found was Intervening against document.write().

I'd take a look at:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

This is probably not causing any errors now but can prevent your js from working as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing the paragraph tags and closing them - there was no difference and the "<" was still there right in front of the table. It seems to be connected to the table code somehow. 

How do I intervene against document.write()? It looks like the problem might be with the webhost software then?

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Wow, that is an easier answer than I thought.